# Mootools + Ruby on Rails ==?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mootools

I just wonder if there is any chance to integrate Mootools into Ruby on Rails with working helpers like remote_function() or page.replace() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use helpers, I would take a look at 
http://code.google.com/p/mootools-rails-helper/

I'm using jQuery in my Rails project without helpers and that works pretty well, too.

Comment: Plugin is slightly outdated (last upload is Oct 2007). And "new Ajax" became "new Request" in mootools, but it is more than nothing, thanks.